# Shipping Help - varied shipping dependent on supplier

Tags: shipping, extensions

I was hoping for some advice from someone. I am in the process of moving my online store from Prestashop to Magento due to Prestashop not having the required shipping modules.

I run an online store manufacturing and distributing car parts. Within our company we manufacture a lot of products, these products vary in size, if a customer purchases a large item and 3 small ones most of the time the smaller ones can go in the large item. This means the customer would only pay for shipping on the large item. What I need is a shipping extension/setup where I can define specific rates defined on what products are purchased. I am not 100% sure how to do this yet, some people have suggested volumetric weight?

I am also taking on lots of new suppliers. Each of these suppliers have their own shipping rates dependent on product size. Some of my suppliers charge £30 UK flat rate for a bonnet plus £20 for a boot lid. What I would need is an extension/setup able to do our in house products and also to add each suppliers product up at a flat rate.

A typical basket might be

```
1 - CarBen Fibre Creations – 2 small, 1 large item = shipping of the large item
2 - Seibon – 1 bonnet = flat rate from supplier based on drop shipping
3 - BC Racing – suspension - flat rate from supplier based on drop shipping
```

Shipping would be 1 (combined total) + 2 + 3

I hope that makes sense, I am still trying to work out if I can calculate my internal items better. Maybe I could put a variable in that states it will only charge for the largest item based on volumetric weight? I am not sure.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look into the Owebia Shipping 2 module.

I've been dealing with it for quite a while now, and you can setup shipping rules based on product attributes as well as cart qty and many other options.

However, you should note that if you're dealing with complex shipping rules you may have a lot of rules to write in order to cover all the possibilites.

I hope it can help

Comment: Thank you I will have a look.

I am not entirely sure how this will work, I currently use weight based shipping on my prestashop but this doesnt work when people place multiple orders.